# JIRA id validation in git commit message

Tags: regex, perl

I am using below Regex pattern on Bitbucket application to validate Jira id in commit message

```
[A-Z][A-Z_0-9]+-[0-9]
```

Sample commit message:

> CLB-181 CLB-168 CLB-84::**** testing 3  jira id CRE-507 validation

Need to validate Jira id(s) before `::` , i.e. `CLB-181 CLB-168 CLB-84::` but not after `::** Testing 3  jira id CRE-507 validation`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
.+(?=::)
```

```
a= 'CLB-181 CLB-168 CLB-84:: testing 3 jira id CRE-507 validation'
re.findall(r'(.+(?=::)', a )
```

**output** --> 
['CLB-181 CLB-168 CLB-84']

Comment: Need a Regex pattern for below two scenarios

Comment: 1. Validate Jira id in commit message
2. Need validate Jira id's before :: if any Jira id specified after :: we need to ignore from validation CLB-181 CLB-168 CLB-84::

Comment: It's your problem, so you have to do at least some of the work yourself. :) It's much better to show the code you are trying to write rather than just explaining what you want. StackOverflow has some good tips for questions in the box to the right of the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

The place many people get hung up in these problems is that they try to match against the entire string. Change the problem so it's easier to solve. In this case, do your steps backward.

Break up the commit message so you have just the portion that you are interested in. Keeping the first element from splitting on `::` is one way to do it:

```
my( $preamble ) = split /::/, $commit_message;
```

Now that you have the first part of the commit message, get the Jira IDs. Matching groups of non-whitespace in list context returns all the matches:

```
my @jira_ids = $preamble =~ m/(\S+)/g;
```

Now validate whatever is in `@jira_ids`.

There are many other ways to do the same thing, so choose one that is simple and maps onto how you and those around you think about the problem (adjusting for problem redefinition :)